# Is Wonder Woman even a Wonder Woman in DC Extended Universe?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In *DC Extended Universe*, Wonder Woman made three appearances till now but I never noticed anybody referring to her as *Wonder Woman*.

Did I miss something or she is not even Wonder Woman in DC Extended Universe?

Comment: Why would it be necessary for anyone to refer to her as "Wonder Woman"?

Comment: @BCdotWEB that didn't invalidate the question either

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I think __BCdotWEB__'s comment is about your question not being clear enough, because out-of-universe there is no doubt that the DCEU's "Diana of Themyscira" is supposed to be "Wonder Woman", even if she has never been referred to as such in-universe. - So maybe you should make it clear whether you are asking if Diana is Wonder Woman in the DCEU, or if your question is about wether Diana has ever been called Wonder Woman in-universe.

Comment: The Batman was just called The Bat, just adding something. Different point, the movie is tited as Wonder Woman, that could count on being identifyable inside DCEU, just saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is not the name she was given or known by in DCEU. Amazons call her Diana. Steve gives her name Diana Prince when they went to assembly. This name is used by everyone else later.

However the name Wonder Woman is only for audience.

There is another thing that nobody knows this name of her. We only see the logo WW on Lex Luthor file, so maybe he gave her that name, but nobody knows it except him *yet*.